# Custom conv2d filter results in error because of different input type tensors

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I want to write a custom conv2d layer for my Pytorch model. Running the code below results in

```
RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.DoubleTensor) should be the same
```

It somehow say "torch.**cuda**.FloatTensor" even if i don't send it to the GPU. Can somebody explain what causes this error, please?

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchsummary import summary


class exampleNet(nn.Module):

    def filters(self):
        w = np.ones([2,2])
        w = torch.tensor(w)
        w = w.view(1, 1, 2, 2)
        return w

    def __init__(self):
        super(exampleNet, self).__init__()   
    
    def forward(self, x):
    
        w = self.filters()
        x = F.conv2d(x, w)
        return x
    
model = exampleNet()
summary(model, (1,10,10))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `summary()` function of [torchsummary](https://github.com/sksq96/pytorch-summary) has an [argument](https://github.com/sksq96/pytorch-summary/blob/345d898d84507b848e92dab4629e03405e19afce/torchsummary/torchsummary.py#L9) named `device=..` which is set to `cuda:0` by default. Just change it to whichever device you want

```
summary(model, (1,10,10), device=torch.device('cpu'))
```

---

Edit (see comments below): Consider using `torchinfo` instead of `torchsummary`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Adding this now gives the Error "AttributeError: 'torch.device' object has no attribute 'lower'", what can be the cause of that?

Comment: I guess you need to do `device='cpu'`. On a separate note, I believe you are supposed to use `torchinfo` which is the upgraded library. `torchsummary` has lots of issues.

Comment: Thanks, using torchinfo, adding a "w=w.float()" to the foward function and "summary(model, (1, 1, 10, 10), device='cpu')" then worked for me!